# How to compare each character in tkinter entry widget to lines in an external text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am programming a typing practice game in Python 3, which utilizes tkinter.
My code so far is able to let the user type something and print what they have typed using a button:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
a=Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
a.pack()
paralist = []
x=random.randint(1,10)
file = open("groupproject.txt")
line = file.readline()
for line in file:
    paralist.append(line.replace("\n", ""));

a.create_text(250,50, text = "Typing Fun", width = 500, font = "Verdana", fill = "purple")
a.create_text(250,300, text = paralist[x], width = 500, font = "Times", fill = "purple")

a = Entry(root, width = 100)
a.pack()
a.focus_set()

def callback():
    s = a.get()
    print (s)

b = Button(root, text="Enter", command=callback)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

My text file is basically 10 one line sentences.

I would like store each character of what the user is typing in the entry widget in a variable (or list or array) as it is being typed (without pressing enter.)

Thank you so much for your help in advance!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entry widgets can be tied to an associated Tkinter string variable (`StringVar` class), which will cause the `StringVar` instance to automatically update when the entry contents change.  Here are the relevant modified lines from your original code:

```
...
a = Entry(root, width = 100)
a_var = StringVar()
a["textvariable"] = a_var
...
```

Now calling the `get()` method on the `a_var` variable will give you the entry contents, and passing a string to its `set()` method will update the entry.

To go a step further, these associated variables allow you to execute a function/method every time the variable changes due to an entry change.  This is helpful if you want to take some action while the user is typing, like comparing the entry contents with one of your example sentences.  Append the following line *after* the `callback` function definition to add this feature:

```
a_var.trace_variable("w", callback)
```

Comment: what is "textvariable" supposed to be? thanks for the help and sorry im a novice at programming especially in python :\